# How to create Options for activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have a couple of questions about activity's

i have a activity which i want to create some options for it. for eg. i want the user to be able to change the font size of text views.

i am a noob in java and eclipse. first i thought i can change the xml values via java but then i found out that i can't and they are read only.

so what is the best solution for creating options which are visual like changing colors and font sizes and picture through entire project?

for eg. i have 10 activities and inside each activity i have some text views. i want to change all of the font sizes. in xml you can create a dimen and all of the text views with `android:fontSize:"@dimen/example` will have the same size. but in java it takes more code and time.

what should i do ? couple of examples would be nice

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so what is the best solution for creating options which are visual
>   like changing colors and font sizes and picture through entire
>   project?

Have a look at the [`setTextSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize) method of the `TextView` class. This will let you set the size of the text programatically.

[`setTextColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor) will let you change the color.

[`setTypeFace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface) will let you change the font.

Having said that about `TextView`, it applies to all the subclasses of `TextView` like `Button`, `EditText`, etc.

---

> i have a activity which i want to create some options for it.

I suggest you create a singleton instance that encapsulates all the information to change the visuals of your activities like text size, typeface, etc. This instance should then be shared among all of your `Activity`s.

---

> couple of examples would be nice

No, an [`SSCCE`](http://www.sscce.org) would be nice. We need to see what you have tried. Code or you didn't do prior research.